# How to batch convert from one image format to another

Tags: imagemagick

I would like use `imagemagick` to convert all TIFF files in a directory to PNG. Is it possible to do it through the `convert` command without a `bash` or `cmd` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mogrify -format tiff *.png
```

thanks to http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/batch-convert-image-formats-imagemagick/

Answer (score 2):

If you have lots of PNG files to convert, and are using a modern, multi-core CPU, you may find you get much better performance using GNU Parallel, like this:

```
parallel convert {} {.}.tiff ::: *.png
```

which will convert all PNG files into TIF files using all your available CPU cores.

I benchmarked 1,000 PNG files, each 1000x1000 pixels and it took 4 minutes with `mogrify` and just 52 seconds using the command above.

[GNU Parallel Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)